# psycopg2 cant connect to postgres DB psycopg2.OperationalError

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

my db setting

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'test',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PORT': '5432',
    'PASSWORD': '1234'
}
```

}

i try `python manage.py migrate` but have [this error](https://pastebin.com/YcKu0whd)

**EDIT**: it happen when i re-install python

Comment: Have you checked your database connection? Do you have postgres running on your machine?

Comment: yes, i can connect to it using pg admin

Comment: Have you created that database?

Comment: Please either answer your own question or delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm stupid, I wrote the wrong password in the settings

Comment: no you are not ... you helped me because i was stupid and i wrote a wrong password, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2` to `django.db.backends.postgresql`.